# React sibling component updates state of parent causing re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'll preface this question by saying I've spent about 3 weeks with React (previously have worked with Vue) so still pretty green.

I have a component structure like the following:

```
const initialState = { propertyA: null, propertyB: null };

const WrapperComponent: FC<Props> = (props) => {

  const [dynamicObject, setDynamicObject] = React.useState(initialState);
  const customCallbackFunction = (newObjectVal) => { setDynamicObject(newObjectVal) };

  return (
    <div>
      <SiblingComponent dynamicObject={dynamicObject} />
      <DifferentSiblingComponent onAction={customCallbackFunction} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Problem I'm facing is each call to `customCallbackFunction` is triggering re-render in both `SiblingComponent` and `DifferentSiblingComponent`. The re-render in `SiblingComponent` is desired, because I want that component to display the dynamic data being emitted by `customCallbackFunction`. However, I'd like to avoid the re-render of `DifferentSiblingComponent`.

For more context, `customCallbackFunction` is being fired on certain hover events on a `canvas` - so the constant re-rendering is causing an infinite callback loop.

Is there a way to handle this without pulling in something like Redux? Any help/insight is appreciated.

Note: I did read that `React.FC` is discouraged, that is  what the team has used in the past so I was just following those templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem I'm facing is each call to `customCallbackFunction` is triggering re-render in both `SiblingComponent` and `DifferentSiblingComponent`.

Yes, that's normal. Unless you do something to prevent it, all child components of the component whose state was updated are updated.

To prevent that in your situation, you need to do two things:

1. Memoize `DifferentSiblingComponent`. Since it's a function component, you'd do that with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).
2. Memoize `customCallbackFunction` with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) or similar so that it's *stable* across the lifecycle of the parent component, rather than being newly created every time the component renders. That way, `DifferentSiblingComponent` sees a stable value, and the memoization works.

   ```
   const customCallbackFunction = useCallback(
       (newObjectVal) => { setDynamicObject(newObjectVal) },
       []
   );
   ```

I go into more detail on this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776226/157247).

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const initialState = { propertyA: null, propertyB: null };

const SiblingComponent = React.memo(({ dynamicObject }) => {
    console.log(`SiblingComponent rendered`);
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(dynamicObject)}</div>;
});

// Just so we can see things change
let counter = 0;

const DifferentSiblingComponent = React.memo(({ onAction }) => {
    console.log(`DifferentSiblingComponent rendered`);
    return (
        <input
            type="button"
            onClick={() => onAction({ ...initialState, counter: ++counter })}
            value="Update"
        />
    );
});

const WrapperComponent /*: FC<Props>*/ = (props) => {
    const [dynamicObject, setDynamicObject] = useState(initialState);
    const customCallbackFunction = useCallback((newObjectVal) => {
        setDynamicObject(newObjectVal);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <SiblingComponent dynamicObject={dynamicObject} />
            <DifferentSiblingComponent onAction={customCallbackFunction} />
        </div>
    );
};
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<WrapperComponent />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a parent rerenders all of its children are rerendered also.
To prevent that [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) might be helpful.

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function DifferentSiblingComponent(props) {
  /* .... */
});
```

After you apply `memo` to one of your components you may need to apply [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to the `customCallbackFunction` so that it is not different during rerenders and doesn't cause `memo` to rerender the component anyway.
e.g.

```
let customCallbackFunction = React.useCallback((newObjectVal) => { setDynamicObject(newObjectVal) },[])
```

Comment: Thanks, the combination of `React.memo` and `React.useCallback` is what I was missing. Accepted a previous answer with an example provided, but this is also answers the question